# Wordpress cropped thumbnail for RSS feed

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the following to generate a thumbnail image in WordPress for an RSS feed:

```
<media:content medium="image" width="128" url="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>" />
```

How can I replace that image with a resized & cropped thumbnail square at 128x128px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) instead.

Obviously you would want to add some error checking, but this would be sample usage given your scenario:

```
// wp_get_attachment_image_src requires the attachment id, so get that first
$attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
// define the desired size as an array in the second option
$image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, array(128,128));
// wp_get_attachment_image_src returns an array: 
// [0] = url, [1] = width, [2] = height, [3] = resized (true / false)
// Retrieve the url from the array
$url = $image_attr[0];

// pass the url into your media element
<media:content medium="image" width="128" url="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```